# How to create marginalia in paged media?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-paged-media

What is the best way to create [marginalia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginalia) in HTML documents for printed (and possibly duplex-printed) output?

It is quite easy to get marginalia for continuous media (like `screen`), e.g. like this:

```
@media screen {
    body {
        padding-left: 32mm;
    }
    .marginalia {      /* not a "margin at-rule" */
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0 -32mm;
        padding: 0;
        width: 30mm;
        text-align: right;
        font-size: smaller;
    }
}
```

But we are out of luck when we want marginalia on paged media, and put them on the right side on `:right` pages, and on the left side on `:left` pages, because:

> The current level of this specification only allows margin at-rules
>   inside ‘@page’.
>   [CSS Paged Media Module Level 3, 5.1: The @page rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-page-20130314/#at-page-rule)

So, how is this supposed to be done, or: How do you do it?

I'd prefer a solution building on current or proposed CSS standards, but I'm afraid there might not be any; therefore, I'm interested as well in proprietary solutions which work for certain user agents, e.g. web browsers or pdf generators, including those which use a proprietary Javascript API.

Answer (score 0):

I admit it's a long shot but if proprietary is an option for you then you may find [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) interesting. It is currently probably [the only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)) layout engine with support for [CSS3 paged media margin boxes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-page/#margin-boxes) which if I understand correctly is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I use page media margin boxes already; [PDFreactor](http://www.pdfreactor.com/) supports them as well. The problem is, there are currently no logical sides `inner` and `outer` for those boxes but only `left` and `right` which makes double-side layouts very cumbersome to do.